# I would like to know if there is any function for managing menu from back end just like wp_nav_menu() in wordpress

Tags: pagination

Iam new to expression engine framework,I would like to know if there is any function for managing menu from back end just like wp_nav_menu() in wordpress

Comment: Please provide more information. What EE version are you using? Do you want to change the Control Panel menu, or manage the menu navigation on the frontend of your website?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the wp thing you are mentioning, however, you could have a look at NavEE https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/navee

Comment: Iam using EE version 3.2.1. I would like to manage the menu in the front end.

Comment: Navee is EE3 compatible as far as i know